# How was Planck able to measure / determine the such small number of $h$?

Tags: experimental-physics, history, physical-constants

Planck constant is equal to $h = 6.62607015\times10^{-34}\ \text{J}⋅\text{Hz}^{−1}$.

I read a little bit about the experiment setup about confining radiation into a black body and 'measuring' the radiation emitted. But how would someone be able to determine such a small number reliably? Each measurement comes with a precision limit and it was more than a hundred years ago. Was it an easy measurement? If not, how did he jump over these limits? What was the methods / wavelengths / devices / algorithm etc. he used?

Comment: This one’s a classic: see Fig.1 and caption of https://www.europhysicsnews.org/articles/epn/pdf/2000/03/epn00303.pdf

Comment: The fact it’s a small number is tied to units.  We can measure $G$ or $e$ both of which are small in MKSA units, but in units where $\hbar=1$ then it is not small.

Comment: If you plot frequency vs stopping potential in the photoelectric effect, $h$ is the slope.

Comment: @gs Does that slope have to be linear? Especially at the very low or very high frequencies?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, what a funny way to say that $2 \pi$ is not a small number :p

Comment: Einstein’s explanation of the photoelectric effect is $E=h\nu$ for *all* frequencies, so yes it would be linear even for high or low frequencies.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So the nature is trying to fit into Einstein's equations? The last question you responded to is not asking about deduction, but about actual and precise observations / measurements on the specified frequencies.

Comment: You question is: does that slope have be linear.  Theory says yes, experiment has not disproved theory yet, and there is no theoretical or experimental reason to suspect it will not linear.  I do not know if this is Nature trying to fit Einstein’s relation, but the relation seems to hold.

Comment: In fact the hypothesis that it is linear is the basis for lots of results on properties of metal…